# Query a multidimensional array property based on other properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here's the scenario...

I have the following multidimensional array:

```
[
    [1, 'red', 'x', true],
    [1, 'red', 'y', true],
    [1, 'red', 'z', false],
    [2, 'red', 'x', true],
    [2, 'red', 'y', false],
    [2, 'red', 'z', false],
    [1, 'blue', 'x', true],
    [1, 'blue', 'y', true],
    [1, 'blue', 'z', false],
    [2, 'blue', 'x', true],
    [2, 'blue', 'y', true],
    [2, 'blue', 'z', false]
]
```

A user can select any two of the first three properties and I need to return a list of true or false for the remaining arrays.

For example if the user selected 'blue' and 'x', I'd return: 1:true, 2:true.

There may not always be 3 options, there could be more or as few as one.

Does anybody have an elegant solution to this?

Comment: Assuming the structure you've shown, there's no particularly elegant way to do it. You have to loop through the outer array looking for matches.

Comment: Does the data have to be structured like this? What's the logic for recognizing that `'blue'` corresponds to the second index rather than the first or third?

Comment: Would probably improve usability if these were objects as opposed to arrays, as well.

Comment: Unfortunately the data structure is not in my control.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Though the loop can be done elegantly, have a look at my answer :-)

Comment: @Bergi: Still be loopin'. :-) But yeah, that's pretty. I couldn't work out what the OP really wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will do this quite elegantly:

```
var data = […];
var selected = [ , 'blue', 'x', ]; // could be any two
                                   // note the sparse array!

var result = data.filter(function(item) {
    return selected.every(function(v, i) {
        return item[i] == v;
    });
}); // [[1,"blue","x",true],
    //  [2,"blue","x",true]]
```

If you want that list as an object, use

```
var key = [0, 1, 2].filter(function(k){ return ! (k in selected); })[0];
var obj = result.reduce(function(m, item) {
    m[item[key]] = item[3];
    return m;
}, {}); // {"1":true,"2":true}
```

Comment: that is so good...and here I was writing this complicated search function that would be modular and work with any dataset, only to find out it is built into JS xD +1

Answer (score 0):

I made a function witch puts the results in to an array, here is the [code pen](http://codepen.io/ZetCoby/pen/NPEgRG)

```
 function getMatch(b,c){
  var found = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i<a.length;i++){
    found = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j<4; j++){
      if(a[i][j] == b){
        found += 1;
      }
      if(a[i][j] == c){
        found += 1;
      }
      if(found == 2){
        found = 0;
        match.push(a[i]);
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ZetCoby but it's not really dynamic enough. I don't know which order data will be selected in or even which order it will be stored in.

Comment: you mean it can be like this [2, 'red', 'y', false], or like this [false, 'red', '2', 'y'], ?

Comment: ok i remade the function, look in the codepen in console, it should output the result the same as before regardless of the input order or order of the array

Answer (score 0):

I made a little function to search an array of data super easily, all you have to is define a map for the data.

**The Function: ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/hg2g2t3p/))**

```
function findInData(data, map, query) {
    var matches = [];       
    data.forEach(function (value) {
        var match = true,
            result = {};
        for (var property in query) {
            if (query.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                if (value[map[property]] !== query[property]) {
                    match = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (match) {
            result[value[0]] = value[map['result']];
            matches.push(result);
        }
    });
    return matches;
}
```

**Example Map (for your data):**

```
var map = {
    color: 1,
    XYZ: 2,
    result: 3
}
```

`color: 1` because the values for colors are in the `[1]` place of the data array

**Example Usage:**

```
var example = findInData(data, map, {color: 'blue', XYZ: 'x'})
```

returns

```
{"1":true}
{"2":true}
```